# Assign flatpak run org.chromium.Chromium to an alias

Tags: bash, chromium, alias, flatpak

I am using https://www.cypress.io/ for react components e2e testing. The CypressJS could not detect the installed Chromium on my computer, because I have installed it with `flatpark`.

One of the contributor of CypresJS told me the following:

> It appears that we do not currently support flatpak browser detection
> due to flatpaked programs not appearing in path. If you can assign
> `flatpak run org.chromium.Chromium` to an alias or a standalone
> executable in $PATH, the autodetection may work.

Is it possible to assign `flatpak run org.chromium.Chromium` to an alias? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append

```
alias chromium="flatpak run org.chromium.Chromium"
```

to your `~/.bashrc` file

e.g. by running

```
echo "alias chromium="flatpak run org.chromium.Chromium"" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Sadly, Jupyter notebook still doesn't see my Firefox :(

Comment: @jena have you installed Firefox via flatpak?

Comment: Yes, of course. I even tried [this](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/1565#issuecomment-1552949170) but no luck.. :/